# show different content in multiple css popups

Tags: html, css, popup

I have this html/css popup code. I want multiple popups in my page. But when I click on another popup, the first popup's content comes on. How can I make them to show different content ? Thank you.

**html**

```
<div id="closed"></div>
<a href="#popup" class="popup-link">Klik untuk memunculkan Popup</a>
<div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup">
<div class="popup-container"><!-- Konten popup, silahkan ganti sesuai kebutuhan -->
<form action="http://www.syakirurohman.net/2015/01/tutorial-membuat-popup-tanpa-javascript-jquery.html#" method="post" class="popup-form">
<h2>Conent</h2>
</div>
</form>
<!-- Konten popup sampai disini--><a class="popup-close" href="#closed">X</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
a.popup-link {
padding:17px 0;
text-align: center;
margin:7% auto;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #FFBA00;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 0px 0px #eea900;
display: block;
}
a.popup-link:hover {
background-color: #ff9900;
box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0px #eea900;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s;
}
/* end link popup*//*style untuk popup */
#popup {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
margin-top: -200px;
}
#popup:target {
visibility:visible;
opacity: 1;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:0;
z-index: 99999999999;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s;
}@media (min-width: 768px){
.popup-container {
width:600px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
.popup-container {
width:100%;
}
}
.popup-container {
position: relative;
margin:7% auto;
padding:30px 50px;
background-color: #333;
color:#fff;
border-radius: 3px;
}a.popup-close {
position: absolute;
top:1px;
right:3px;
background-color: #fff;
padding:7px 10px;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 1;
color:#333;
}/* style untuk isi popup */.popup-form {
margin:10px auto;
}
.popup-form h2 {
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 37px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You need to create multiple divs for each popup and than show the popup that you need to show..

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks. but I'm new to the html/css. If you can give me an example html would be great.

Comment: _“But when I click on another popup, the first popup's content comes on”_ – that probably means that you simply copy&pasted the HTML structure, leaving the ids in place as they are(?). Ids must be unique within an HTML document. (And the selectors in your CSS will have to be adapted as well then.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full code for minimalist popups.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.popup').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).attr('data-popup')).show();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  display:none;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup" id="popup1">
  Popup 1
  </div>
  
  <div class="popup" id="popup2">
  Popup 2
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn" data-popup="popup1">Open pop 1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-popup="popup2">Open pop 2</button>
```

Comment: Hi @mosh. This looks useful, may I know how you created the "Full page" popup? I don't see the code for that here.

Comment: I guess that you mean to [this](https://i.imgur.com/9mfk4uY.png) button. If so, this button was generated by StackOverflow to let the users to watch the snippet result on "full page". If you need help to create button like this, please ask a new question and paste the URL here and I will be happy to help. If not, what do you mean?